# How do you select an option from a multiple option interatcive installer?

Tags: text-user-interface

I'm sure it's obvious, but I have been pressing every key and can't select the "SDL12 and OpenAL source code" option in this installer. Pressing Enter/Return does either the OK or Cancel action.

[image: Screenshot of interactive installer with multiple options to choose from]

I have no idea what to call these things so it's been really hard to find the answer I need. It was a challenge to even come up with tags for this place.

What do I do to / how do I select  the "SDL12 and OpenAL source code" option?

(and optionally, what in the world was I *supposed to search* to find the answer?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need press the spacebar.

Answer (score 3):

A lot of these things follow the Common User Access (CUA) 1991 conventions.
The giveaway here is the highlighted letters on the buttons and the way that the pseudo-window borders and the groupbox borders are coloured.
Many Microsoft/IBM programs for text-mode MS-DOS, PC-DOS, and OS/2 had these conventions and looked like this.

In dialogues:

- <kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd> plus the underlined letter of a button or menu option clicks that button or menu option, wherever the keyboard focus may be on the dialogue.  This is an "accelerator key".  (Often TUI programs on Unices and Linux-based operating systems don't *quite* work like CUA 1991 programs on DOS and OS/2 did, because of the convention of how the <kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd> key turns things into escape sequences on Unices and Linux-based operating systems.  Sometimes the letter on its own, sans modifier key, is the accelerator key.)
- <kbd>⎋ Esc</kbd> and <kbd>⮠  Return</kbd>/<kbd>Enter</kbd> are accelerators that usually click cancel or OK buttons, wherever the keyboard focus may be on the dialogue.  (Again, because of the way that terminals work, which wasn't a concept on DOS and OS/2, there's usually a small delay before the <kbd>⎋ Esc</kbd> key takes effect where it is important not to type anything more.)
- Checkboxes are a form of button.  They can have accelerator keys.  When they actually have the input focus, the spacebar toggles them on and off.
- When other buttons actually have the input focus, the spacebar also acts like a click on the button.
- <kbd>⇥ Tab</kbd> and <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd>+<kbd>⇥ Tab</kbd> move the keyboard input focus around.